# CoreOS v.1.6.1 not starting

Tags: kubernetes, coreos

I am working on setting up a new Kubernetes cluster using the CoreOS documentation.  This one uses the CoreOS v1.6.1 image.  I am following this documentation from link [CoreOS Master setup](https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/deploy-master.html). I looked in the journalctl logs and I see that the kubeapi-server seems to exit and restart.

The following is a journalctl log indicating on the kube-apiserver :

> checking backoff for container "kube-apiserver" in pod "kube-apiserver-10.138.192.31_kube-system(16c7e04edcd7e775efadd4bdcb1940c4)"
>
> Back-off 5m0s restarting failed container=kube-apiserver pod=kube-apiserver-10.138.192.31_kube-system(16c7e04edcd7e775efadd4bdcb1940c4)
>
> Error syncing pod 16c7e04edcd7e775efadd4bdcb1940c4 ("kube-apiserver-10.138.192.31_kube-system(16c7e04edcd7e775efadd4bdcb1940c4)"), skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "kube-apiserver" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 5m0s restarting failed container=kube-apiserver pod=kube-apiserver-10.138.192.31_kube-system(16c7e04edcd7e775efadd4bdcb1940c4)"

I am wondering if it's because I need to start the new etcd3 version instead of the etcd2?  Any hints or suggestion is appreciated.

The following is my cloud-config:

> ```
> coreos:
> etcd2:
> # generate a new token for each unique cluster from https://discovery.etcd.io/new:
> discovery: https://discovery.etcd.io/33e3f7c20be0b57daac4d14d478841b4
> # multi-region deployments, multi-cloud deployments, and Droplets without
> # private networking need to use $public_ipv4:
> advertise-client-urls: http://$private_ipv4:2379,http://$private_ipv4:4001
> initial-advertise-peer-urls: http://$private_ipv4:2380
> # listen on the official ports 2379, 2380 and one legacy port 4001:
> listen-client-urls: http://0.0.0.0:2379,http://0.0.0.0:4001
> listen-peer-urls: http://$private_ipv4:2380
> fleet:
> public-ip: $private_ipv4   # used for fleetctl ssh command
> units:
>  - name: etcd2.service
>  command: start
> ```

However, I have tried with CoreOS v1.5 images and they work fine.  It's the CoreOS v1.6 images that I am not able to get the kube-apiserver running for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use etcd2, so you need to pass the flag '--storage-backend=etcd2' to your kube-apiserver in your manifest.

Answer (score 1):

You are using etcd2, I think maybe you can try etcd3.

You said:

> I am wondering if it's because I need to start the new etcd3 version instead of the etcd2? Any hints or suggestion is appreciated.

I would like to recommend that you can read [this doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/configure-upgrade-etcd/) to learn how to upgrade the etcd.